# Reference Request: Intuition for Cross Products

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, reference-request, vector-analysis, cross-product

I recall reading a blog post a long (~10 years?) ago that gave some intuition for how to reason with cross product identities via infinitesimals, and I cannot find it now for the life of me. Does anyone recall seeing anything like this?

Comment: Do you mean infinitesimal generators of $SO(3)$ rotations, or something else?

Comment: @J.G. honestly do not remember, but I think it came from a kind of non-rigorous physics perspective so I don't know if they'd be that explicit